# How can i take a given dict and return a new one with multiple values for one key?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm new to python and struggling with this question - Create a function which works as follows:

```py
d={1:"x",2:"y",3:"x",4:"z"}

invert_d(d)
{"x":(1,3),"y":(2),"z":(4)}
```

So `invert_d` gives a new dict with the values of multiple keys as lists.

I have to say, that I never worked with dicts and started python 1 week ago...so I'm a total newb.

I am new to python.... and I'm struggling with this question:

Edit: I read wrong and fixed the Dict. Sorry guys :(

Also we cant import in the exam

Comment: The keys in a dictionary must be unique. Your `d` isn't a valid dictionary.

Comment: @ChrisCharley it is syntactically a valid dictionary. But at the end it will just preserve the later value of key.

Comment: @ChrisCharley Sorry, i read wrong and fixed the Dict. i accidentally swapped key and value :x

Answer (score 1):

You can use the setdefault method to make the dictionary construction simpler.  A very basic way to do it is like this:

```
d={1:"x",2:"y",3:"x",4:"z"}

def invertDict(d):
    result = dict()
    for k,v in d.items(): result.setdefault(v,[]).append(k)
    return result

print(invertDict(d))

{'x': [1, 3], 'y': [2], 'z': [4]}
```

If you want a one-liner solution, you can use a dictionary comprehension.  Here's one that outputs the list of keys as tuples:

```
def invertDict(d):
    return {v:tuple(inv[v]) for inv in [{}] for k,v in d.items() if [inv.setdefault(v,[]).append(k)] }

print(invertDict(d))

{'x': (1, 3), 'y': (2,), 'z': (4,)}
```

Answer (score 0):

A dict associates exactly one value with a particular key, so your original dict `d` would see two different values for the key "x" (first 1 and then 3), and the last one would replace previous ones.  If you have access to an interactive Python session, this looks like:

```
$ python
Python 3.9.1 (default, Dec 13 2020, 11:55:53) 
[GCC 10.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> d = {"x": 1, "y": 2, "x": 3, "z": 5}
>>> d
{'x': 3, 'y': 2, 'z': 5}
```

(The `d` by itself there just asks Python to use `print` to display the current value, as if you had called `print(d)`.)

So at this point you have some options.  You could just define a dict to contain the eventual values you want: `{"x":(1,3),"y":(2,),"z":(5,)}`.  Or, if you actually have a source of a stream or list of pairs of values that you want to process into a dict using a function like the one you describe, we can do that, too, but we need to use something like a list of tuples as the input, rather than a dict: `l = [("x", 1), ("y", 2), ("x", 3), ("z", 5)]`.  With that new notion of the input, we could write a function that in some way processes each element of that list and compiles those elements into a particular dict.  Here's one way that could look (without any error handling):

```
from functools import reduce

def add_tuple_to_dict(d, t): # here `d` is the dict and `t` is the tuple
  if t[0] in d:
    d[t[0]].append(t[1])
  else:
    d[t[0]] = [t[1],]
  return d

def invert_d(list_of_tuples):
  return reduce(add_tuple_to_dict, list_of_tuples, {})
```

Edit: after submitting the above, I now realize you do actually want to invert your dict, which could look like this, instead:

```
from functools import reduce

def add_tuple_to_dict(d, t): # here `d` is the dict and `t` is the tuple
  if t[1] in d:
    d[t[1]].append(t[0])
  else:
    d[t[1]] = [t[0],]
  return d

def invert_d(d):
  return reduce(add_tuple_to_dict, d.items(), {})
```

Comment: thanks, in the exam we cant import new things and have to work with basics python gives

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to initially create your dictionary having keys with lists as values. Then convert it to a dict having keys with tuples as values:

```py
import collections

d = {1: "x", 2: "y", 3: "x", 4: "z"}

def invert(d):
    # first as a dict with lists as values
    inv = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for k, v in d.items():
        # note that the previous VALUE is the key of the inverted dict
        inv[v].append(k)
    
    # then convert the existing "list of values" to "tuples of values"
    inv = {k: tuple(v) for k, v in inv.items()}
    
    return inv

invert(d)
# {'x': (1, 3), 'y': (2,), 'z': (4,)}
```

What `defaultdict` does is when a value in the dict is looked up (get or set), if it doesn't exist, it automatically creates a value with the default *factory* provided. In this case, `list`.
So each value *when looked up* is set to an empty list. In the loop, the new values (keys of the old one), are *appended* to this list. If it didn't exist before, the new value is appended to the empty list. If it did exist (from a previous iteration) and has a value, then a new value is appended to that list.

Since what you want at the end is tuples of values and not lists, I have a *dictionary comprehension* which uses the same keys and converts the values to tuples.

Comment: thanks, in the exam we cant import new things and have to work with basics python gives

Comment: `collections` is not an external package, it's part of the "basics" Python comes with. If you don't want to or can't import external packages, then mention that clearly in your question.

Comment: Sorry, i fixed it

Comment: You can add a version where the logic I've explained is coded in explicitly. _How it should work_ is in the explanation of my answer. Try writing it yourself first.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a reverse look-up

```py
invert_d = lambda d: { v:[k for k in d if d[k] == v] for v in d.values() }
```

whereat you can read `v` as *value* and `k` as *key*.

```py
d={1:"x",2:"y",3:"x",4:"z"}
invert_d(d)

{'x': [1, 3], 'y': [2], 'z': [4]}
```

**Edit**

Maybe a brief explanation: This is a [Lambda Expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) using two [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#list-comprehensions). One as value and an outer one to wrap it up (actually a dictionary comprehensions but works the same).
This is not really performant but totally sufficient for every day usage.